# Cannot implicitly convert type 'frmRemote.RemoteClickHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

create event press mouse.

In frmRemote:

```
public delegate void RemoteClickHandler(MouseEventArgs e);
public event RemoteClickHandler RemoteClick;
```

In frmScreen:

```
public frmScreen(frmRemote remote)
{
 InitializeComponent();  
 remote.Click += new frmRemote.RemoteClickHandler(remote_Click);  
}
 void remote_Click(MouseEventArgs e){  
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'frmRemote.RemoteClickHandler' to
>   'System.EventHandler'

I don't understand why it's getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong.

```
remote.Click += new frmRemote.RemoteClickHandler(remote_Click);
```

but I think you have to do

```
remote.RemoteClick += new frmRemote.RemoteClickHandler(remote_Click);
```